# python tornado 404 with vuejs

Tags: python, vue.js, tornado

I'm trying to serve a Vue.js project with [tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable) and I'm getting this error:

```
INFO:tornado.access:304 GET / (::1) 11.05ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /css/app.bd8aa8d9.css (::1) 3.97ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /js/chunk-vendors.a3ecb371.js (::1) 5.88ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /js/app.d1ab8cb6.js (::1) 1.22ms
```

And this is my code:

```
class ChameleonApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": './Site'}),
            (r"/websocket", ChameleonWebSocket)]

        settings = dict(
            debug=True,
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./Site"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./Site")
        )

        super(ChameleonApplication, self).__init__(handlers, **settings)
```

[image]

And this is the project structure.

Comment: Your regex for StaticFileHandler is same as MainHandler. Move WebSocket handler 2nd, and put static last with regex `r'/(.*)'`

Comment: did as said 
`      handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/websocket", ChameleonWebSocket),
            (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": './Site'})
`
but still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

this code fixed the problem

```
class ChameleonApplication(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/websocket", ChameleonWebSocket),
            (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler,
             {"path": r"{0}".format(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "site"))}),
        ]

        settings = dict({
            "template_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "site"),
            "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "site"),
            "debug": True
            }
        )

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the tornado docs:

> .."This setting will automatically make all requests that start
>   with /static/ serve from that static directory, e.g.
>   http://localhost:8888/static/foo.png will serve the file foo.png from
>   the specified ..."

So you need to access the static files with:

```
http(s)://yourhost:yourport/Site/css/somefile.css
```

The static file handler will handle all requests to /Site/* by your definition.

You can also delete the:
Static route "/" you added.

As a general remark: I would recommend to use all lowercase directory names when dealing with webapps / apths, just to avoid problems with different OS behaviours ...